# Difficulty with map's find function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am having trouble figuring out why this is not compiling. This is just the basic class declaration, constructor/destructor and other functions are left out. Message is also properly defined somewhere else.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class SmartCarrier {
        map<string, vector <Message *>> accounts_map;
        void SearchMessage() const;

    };
```

When I try to assign m_iter with `m_iter = accounts_map.find(account)` I get the error no operator "=" matches these operands. I double checked to make sure the map iterator was the same type as the actual map which it is. I'm not sure what is incorrect.

```
void SmartCarrier::SearchMessage() const {
        string account;
        map<string, vector<Message *>>::iterator m_iter;
        cout << "Enter an account: ";
        cin >> account;
        try {
            m_iter = accounts_map.find(account);
            if (m_iter != accounts_map.end) {
                  //code to display account information
            } else {
                throw 'e';
            }
        } catch (char e) {
            cout << "Error: Account not found\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: `accounts_map.end` ===> `accounts_map.end()`

Comment: Your method `SearchMessage` is marked `const`. Therefore, the accounts_map becomes `const`. The `find` method on a `const` map returns a `const_terator`, not plain `iterator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SearchMessage()` is declared as `const`, so its `this` parameter is pointing at a `const SmartCarrier` object, so its `accounts_map` member is also `const`.  When `find()` is called on a `const map`, it returns a `const_iterator` instead of an `iterator`.

Also, `accounts_map.end` needs to be `accounts_map.end()` instead.

Also, using an exception the way you are is just wasted overhead that you can (and should) get rid of.

Try this:

```
void SmartCarrier::SearchMessage() const {
    string account;
    cout << "Enter an account: ";
    cin >> account;
    map<string, vector<Message *>>::const_iterator m_iter = accounts_map.find(account);
    if (m_iter != accounts_map.end()) {
        //code to display account information
    } else {
        cout << "Error: Account not found\n";
    }
}
```

If you are using C++11 or later, consider using `auto` instead of `const_iterator` explicitly, that would also fix the error:

```
auto m_iter = accounts_map.find(account);
```